# send email with attachment on python + jquery

Tags: html, jquery, python-3.x, flask

I have the code of email sending on `python` from one email address to another using `smtplib`. Besides email, I need to send attachment(f.ex image). I can upload and view any image I want through `jquery`.
The question is:

**How to send this image to Flask, to send it as attachment?**

`python`

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
 
msg = MIMEMultipart()

password = "your_password"
msg['From'] = "your_address"
msg['To'] = "to_address"
msg['Subject'] = "Photos"
 
msg.attach(MIMEImage(file("google.jpg").read()))
 
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
server.starttls()
server.login(msg['From'], password)
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
server.quit()
print "successfully sent email to %s:" % (msg['To'])

return render_template('upload.html')
```

`upload.html`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input type='file' class="form-control" id="imgInp" style="width: 80%;">
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="" style="width: 20%; height: 20%; margin-left: 10px;">

<script>
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
}); 
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the `email` docs, the proper way going about iterating over a list of pictures in the example given would look like this:

```
with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
    img_data = fp.read()
msg.add_attachment(img_data, maintype='image', subtype=imghdr.what(None, img_data))
```

Where `file` is the name of the file. You will need to import the `imghdr` library.

The important thing to note is that you open the file with the built in `open` function to get the image data and store it in a variable. Then you just add it to your attachment.
For more info here's a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html). It'll be the the third example.

Comment: I got this error: `NameError: name 'pngfiles' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but pngfiles is just a list of images defined earlier in the example. If you can store the file in a variable you don't need a for loop. You just replace it with `file`

Comment: thanks for response, but I do not have a list of image. I just need to choose them randomly. Could you please show it without loop?

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution, just add `MIMEApplication`

```
file = request.form['file']
file_to_send = MIMEApplication(open(file, 'rb').read())
file_to_send.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file)
msg.attach(file_to_send)
```